# iphone memory usage

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, consumption

After running with the memory analyzer, my app seems to increase its memory consumption very slowly.

The analyzer did detect memory leaks whenever certain events occur, which i quickly fixed. But this slow consumption of memory is occuring when im not doing anything in the app. The app basically just starts. Consumption is more noticeable when I touch an object and move it about.

Is there an undetectable leak in my app or is this normal behavior (perhaps of internal framework libraries)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Leaks tool detects programming errors (object going out of scope without being freed) but cannot detect semantic errors. A common error of this type is to hold on to something after you're finished with it in an array or in a global variable. One iPhone-specific cause I've seen is to keep pushing views into a UINavigationController without cleaning up the ones you aren't going to use anymore.

Comment: im seeing slow yet constant memory increases, just by letting the app sit and do nothing. though realistically it is rendering stuff ever 1 second via an NSTimer.

im also doing a bit of CG... stuff (to render quartz related graphics). maybe this has something to do with memory not being released.

also, i do have a few view controllers. but they are autoreleased. so i believe im ok in that area.

Thanks.

Comment: Also... i was apparantly mis-reading the analyzer. I was watching the "overall bytes" column - specifically i was assuming i had a drastic memory leak(s) everywhere since this column kept rising.

Answer (score 0):

some times memory analtzer also not able to track leaks in our application . Best way is that  when your memory consumption is increase , in that controller check wether all objects are properly released or not.